# SQL Server Type Cast for DateTime field and UNION ALL

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting, union, union-all

I am facing a strange behaviour of SQL Server (T-SQL) when it comes to using `UNION ALL` and having to pad one table (the one to be joined by the `UNION` command).

Table 1:

```
Firstname  Lastname  Date
---------  --------  ----
Peter      Pan       2013-01-21 12:29:55.000
Paul       Am        2013-01-22 12:39:45.000
```

and Table 2:

```
FN         LN
---------  --------
Laura      Loeb
Lisa       Lefteye
```

I want to do a `UNION ALL` to both tables. Which can only be achieved by "padding" Table 2 with a "fake" third column (since it has no "data" column), like so:

```
SELECT
  Firstname AS FName, Lastname AS LName, Date AS TheDate
FROM Table1

UNION ALL

SELECT
  FN AS FName, LN AS LName, NULL AS TheDate
FROM Table2
```

My problem is: SQL Server gives me an error message telling me that it cannot cast to `DateTime` type.

I am 100% sure that my datatype for column `Date` in Table1 is set to `DateTime`, NULL values are allowed, too.

I have tried setting a dummy date, like so:

```
... FN AS FName, LN AS LName, '2013-03-08' AS TheDate ...
```

I have tried setting the current date, like so:

```
... FN AS FName, LN AS LName, getdate() AS TheDate ...
```

None of the above work.

However, I know that the solution in general (padding missing columns by using "NULL AS Columnname") works...

Does anybody know how to solve that problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: It only happens when I try to pad a column of type DateTime with NULL or with a dummy date or with getdate(). If I try to pad a column of type vchar or bit, it all works fine...

Comment: Thank you very much, after spending half a day trying to find the error, I found it: I was not aware of the fact that the SELECTed Columns had to be in the same order when using UNION ALL.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what the problem is...

```
SELECT '1' A, '2' B, GETDATE() C
UNION ALL
SELECT '1', '2', NULL
```

**Returns**

```
| A | B |                            C |
----------------------------------------
| 1 | 2 | March, 08 2013 16:34:31+0000 |
| 1 | 2 |                       (null) |
```

Have you tried to `CAST` your `NULL`?

Comment: Hi Aarolama Bluenk, thank you for your help! I've just checked, and ... SELECT CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) AS TheDate ... still gives me the same error (Message 241, Level 16, Status 1, Line 1)...

Comment: Found the error - see my last comment to my question. Thanks again for your help (in confirming that I at least got the padding part right).

Answer (score 1):

What you have already posted works fine.

```
SELECT 'Frank' As 'Name', 'Grimes' as 'Name2', GETDATE() as 'TheDate'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Jim' As 'Name', 'Bloggs' as 'Name2', null as 'TheDate'
```

Comment: Hi CathaMF, thank you for your help. I've just now checked to see if the view I am using the statement in causes the problem. But that is not the case... Still looking for a solution, and clueless. Thank you for confirming that at least I am thinking in the right direction.

Comment: Found the error - see my last comment to my question. Thanks again for your help (in confirming that I at least got the padding part right).